# Apache-2 proxypass exclusion with SSL

Tags: apache2, apache-config

I use Jboss +Apache solution. [Please see my httpd-vhost.conf file below]

I tried to exclude my images folder from proxy redirection.

What I try to do is, pick images from /usr/local/images/ alias when I use **http**://www.mysite.com/images and **https**://www.mysite.com/images links.

This is working fine with virtual host port 80 but when I do same configurations on virtual host port 443 it’s not picking up images from /usr/local/images/ alias and redirect to Jboss.

In other words http://www.mysite.com/images link is working but **https**://www.mysite.com/images is not working with same configurations.

Also please note that rest of SSL configurations are working fine. I can access https://www.mysite.com without any issue.

Can anyone please help on this?

```
<VirtualHost www.mysite.com:80>
ServerName www.mysite.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /images !
Alias /images/ /usr/local/images/
ProxyPass / http://www.mysite.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.mysite.com:8080/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost www.mysite.com:443>
ServerName www.mysite.com
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile "\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\conf\mysite.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\conf\mysite.key.insecure"
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /images !
Alias /images/ /usr/local/images/
ProxyPass / http://www.mysite.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.mysite.com:8080/
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /usr/local/images/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Mistakenly I had uploaded incorrect httpd-vhost.conf file. Now I have corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

What I have done is create separate httpd-ssl.conf file and Listen 443. Other configurations are same.

Please see my httpd-ssl.conf file below.

Thanks

```
Listen 443

<VirtualHost www.mysite.com:443>
 ServerName www.mysite.com
 SSLEngine On
 SSLCertificateFile "\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\conf\mysite.crt"
 SSLCertificateKeyFile "\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\conf\mysite.key.insecure"
 SSLProxyEngine On
 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass /images !
 Alias /images/ /usr/local/images/
 ProxyPass / https://www.mysite.com:7443/
 ProxyPassReverse / https://www.mysite.com:7443/
</VirtualHost>
```